# Is there a word (or phrase) that describe a series of mishaps/misfortunes in one's life?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I don't mean something like 'many hardships' or 'several tragedies'. I'm looking for a word or short phrase that would describe just a really rough spot or time frame in someone's life. For instance, [s]he was fired, lost a loved one and/or a friend, a pet died, [s]he wasn't getting much support from those around him/her. How can I describe such a cluster of emotional events in a simple way?

Comment: Lemony Snicket's ?

Comment: "Life" is how I tend to describe it.

Comment: are you looking for a cliche? or for phrases generally? You might say something like "for a while her life was tragedy after tragedy".

Answer (score 10):

A bad patch. I've heard rough patch, too, but more commonly bad patch or rough time. I suppose sticky patch is chiefly British.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/go-through-a-bad-difficult-rough-sticky-patch

Comment: I've heard "bad/rough/stick patch" regularly applied to problems in relationships (e.g. "Their relation is going through a rough patch right now.") or other more specific instances (like problem at work, or problems with kids, etc.), but I can't say that I've ever heard it applied to life in general.

Comment: In Britain, the expression I think you are thinking of is 'sticky wicket', which is not applicable in this context. But we don't use the expression 'sticky patch' in this context, either. Despite what dictionary.Cambridge.org might say! It is too trivial in meaning to be a synonym for 'tragedy'.

Answer (score 10):

1. Trial and tribulation.
2. Ordeal.

i.e.: *A period of trial and tribulation.*

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trials+and+tribulations

Comment: just out of curiosity: any idea whether the phrase "trials and tribulations" is etymologically based on the story of Job in the Christian Bible?

Comment: Would fit Hercules just as well.

Answer (score 6):

[Adversity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adversity):

> - a state or instance of serious or continued difficulty or misfortune.
>
>   - he had to cope with life's many adversities; she showed courage in the face of adversity.

also  [vicissitudes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vicissitude)  : (from M-W)

> - difficulties  or hardship attendants on a way of life, a career, or a course of action and usually beyond one's control.

Answer (score 5):

"**A string of bad luck**" [1] is often used for a series of bad events in short order. Perhaps most commonly for a series of failures. (That is, the death of a pet is usually not a failure on your part, nor "bad luck", but a bad investment or denting your car is.)

For instance: "First I had a customer pull out of a project, but I had a lead on another sale until my contact in that company quit and then we didn't get funding for my third project because I was too busy firefighting. I'm telling you, I just had a string of bad luck this quarter!"

[1] http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+string+of+bad+luck

Comment: A pet dying is not bad luck, and least of all is losing a loved one. The idiom is used when nothing seems to be going your way. When everything you try, fails, through sheer bad luck. As if destiny were dealing you rotten cards.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: You are right, a very good way of putting it

Comment: But one could indeed hear "a string of bad luck" used to describe a series of misfortunes that included something as serious as the death of a loved one. "She's had a string of bad luck, poor dear."  It would be a kind of understatement, bordering on euphemism.

Answer (score 4):

If all the unfortunate events take place within the same year, then that year might be an '[Annus horribilis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annus_horribilis)'. It's latin but it's widely understood in British English, since the Queen's usage of it in 1992.

> Although the phrase is cited by the Oxford English Dictionary as being in use as early as 1985, it was brought to prominence by Queen Elizabeth II, in a speech to the Guildhall on 24 November 1992, marking the 40th anniversary of her accession, in which she described the closing of the year as an annus horribilis.
>
> *1992 is not a year on which I shall look back with undiluted pleasure. In the words of one of my more sympathetic correspondents, it has turned out to be an Annus Horribilis.*

Comment: This may be well understood to a BrE speaker, but I can't say that I've ever heard used by a layperson in AmE.

Comment: I've heard it.  A bit "out there", though.

Comment: Yes. I've edited my answer to specify BrE.

Comment: Great suggestion; I think the antonym "annus mirabilis" is especially satisfying

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford Dictionary of English Idioms suggests

**a chapter of accidents**

> Definition: [a series of unfortunate events](http://books.google.it/books?id=g9ynBrageYIC&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=idiom%20for%20series%20of%20unfortunate%20events&source=bl&ots=hEHlCaLt86&sig=pEJ8Vu9Ps0y2LRnjDfzvUKa6vSU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tEpkVOmkCs6sPYaugcgD&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=idiom%20for%20series%20of%20unfortunate%20events&f=false)
>   This expression was apparently coined by Lord Chesterfield in a letter to Solomon Dayrolles in 1753: "The chapter of knowledge is a very short, but the **chapter of accidents** is a very long one"

Comment: I had to Ctrl-F or would of missed the cliched *series of unfortunate events*. I've never heard 'chapter of *accidents*'; *events*, maybe. +1 for the cliche that this question should be asking to avoid.

Comment: @Mazura   I agree with your observations, and  I feel "chapter of events" wouldn't necessarily express a run of unfortunate incidents. (Trying to avoid the clichè)

Comment: When asked "What happened to her?" one might reply "There was a chapter of events..." The context defines it and tone usually requests that we *not get into it*. I have never heard 'chapter/series of *fortunate* events'.

Answer (score 1):

One common formulation is "a litany of troubles [or problems]," where *litany* has the sense of "a sizable series or set." The entry for *litany* in Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) shows an interesting line of meanings:

> **litany** *n* (13c) **1 :** a prayer consisting of a series of invocations and supplications by the leader with alternate responses by the congregation **2 a :** a resonant or repetitive chant {a *litany* of cheering phrases—Herman Wouk} **b :** a usu. lengthy recitation or enumeration {a familiar *litany* of complaints} **c :** a sizable series or set {a *litany* of problems}

All three of MW's nonliturgical definitions of *litany* have emerged within the past seventy years—definition 2a in the Seventh Collegiate (1963), definition 2b in the Ninth Collegiate (1983), and definition 2c in the Eleventh Collegiate (2003).

Merriam-Webster's unhurried recognition of meaning 2c notwithstanding, use of the word in that sense goes back almost a century. The first instance of "litany of troubles" that a Google Books search finds is in David Hamilton, [*Pale Warriors: A Novel*](http://books.google.com/books?id=8_qRuQsCwYwC&q=%22litany+of+troubles%22&dq=%22litany+of+troubles%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3PRkVJ3tGIeIigLkxYHoBw&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAw) (1929):

> "There's no moon to-night," she said. "You ought to know that. Now, Thaddeus, dear, I am sure you will forgive me if I hurry away without reciting my **litany of troubles** to you, comforting and reassuring as you are.

More clearly relevant to the OP's question is this occurrence from Caryll Houselander, [*The Dry Wood*](http://books.google.com/books?id=MZIQAQAAIAAJ&q=%22litany+of+troubles%22&dq=%22litany+of+troubles%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3PRkVJ3tGIeIigLkxYHoBw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg) (1947):

> From house to house went Father O'Grady, listening to the same **litany of troubles**, the aches and pains of rheumatism, the damp seeping into the walls, the swarms of rats, the way the landlord wouldn't repair the roof (God have mercy on the black-hearted devil), the long wait at the Labour Exchange, the hardness of the Means Test, the children who had to be hidden when the inspectors came, the new flats with hot water laid on where you mayn't have children or dogs or cats, so no one can live in them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fits what you're looking for but another option may be "A tragedy of errors"

Comment: Isn't that a play on the name of Shakespeare's "A comedy of errors"? I'd have assumed that it had a theatrical meaning rather than a life-stage one.

Answer (score 0):

For those seeking a bit more artful phrasing, I propose:

> (tempest-)**tossed upon life's billows**

*Tempest-tost* (also *tempest-tossed*), meaning "pounded or hit repeatedly by storms or adversities<sup>[1](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/tempest-tost)</sup>" when used figuratively, has a long history, dating back to the late 16th century<sup>[2](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tempest-tossed)</sup>.

The word has seen a fair bit of poetic use, perhaps most famously in the Emma Lazarus sonnet "The New Colossus":

> Give me your tired, your poor,
>   Your huddled masses yearning to breathe free,
>   The wretched refuse of your teeming shore.
>   Send these, the homeless, **tempest-tost** to me,
>   I lift my lamp beside the golden door!

As for "upon life's billows," the phrase appears to have <strike>originated</strike> been popularized in the 1897 hymn "Count Your Blessings" by Johnson Oatman, Jr.:

> **When upon life’s billows you are tempest tossed**,
>   When you are discouraged, thinking all is lost,
>   Count your many blessings name them one by one,
>   And it will surprise you what the Lord hath done.<sup>[3](https://www.hymnal.net/en/hymn/h/707)</sup>

An Internet search will reveal that "(tempest)-tossed upon life's billows" has seen some use without becoming cliché.

An example of the phrase in use, from [*A Memoir of Eli Bickford: A Patriot of the Revolution*](http://archive.org/stream/memoirofelibickf01bush/memoirofelibickf01bush_djvu.txt) by Charles Ira Bushnell, published in 1865:

> Yet the freshness of youth still lingered around his heart, rendering him a fitting companion for every age, and children and youth, as they gazed upon him, felt that even age had its attractions. When a century had passed by, and left him still **tossed upon life's billows**, thought left the busy present, and wandered back to the bright scenes of the past, and the old man was a child again.

<sup>1 https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/tempest-tost</sup>
<sup>2 http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tempest-tossed</sup>
<sup>3 https://www.hymnal.net/en/hymn/h/707</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If the series of unfortunate events inevitably lead to an undesirable outcome (such as going bankrupt, or having a nervous breakdown) you could use "perfect storm," a term popularized by the book and movie called "The Perfect Storm." by Sebastian Junger (1997, 2000). ("Perfect storm" predates Junger's work.)

"The losses were her perfect storm. We weren't surprised to hear that she spent some time in the care of a psychiatrist that summer."

Answer (score -1):

Here's a different perspective : "Splintered by stress" (http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/splintered-by-stress/)

Answer (score -1):

The Chinese phrase "May you live in interesting times". Means may you have lots of mishaps and events that cause your life to be interesting.... It means the same thing (as above) but in a veiled way that sounds like they are wishing a nice thing on you.